# Can I use APC machines in the US with passport of new nationality?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

I am a dual Italian/Swiss citizen who naturalized as British in 2020. I now have three nationalities. I have been to the US several times after 2008, using the Swiss or Italian passport (choice depended on passport validity each time), but not since 2015. I'm soon going to the US on holiday, and will be using my British passport as I'll be flying out of and back to the UK. Will I be considered a returning ESTA passenger and able to use the Automatic Border Control machines with my new British passport?

Edit: the airport of arrival in the US would be JFK T8.

Comment: Don’t know the answer to the actual question, but you will need a new ESTA, and you will have to disclose your other nationalities and passports so it’s likely they will be able to link all those together.

Comment: Thanks. I applied for a new ESTA in November, before I made actual plans. They also asked me for current/previous passports and ID cards of any nationality I hold, but I couldn't input the numbers of the previous passports I used to travel to the US as I had run out of space inputting the numbers of the current ones... Though I guess they can still link all of them together thanks to bio data and fingerprints anyway.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason not to use your Italian or Swiss passport to enter the US, unless they are expired/close to expired - where you are coming from doesn't matter.

Comment: Correct, @ajd - I always travel to EU and back to the US this way; for check in, show one passport, for immigration, the other